# SwiftUI, cannot dismiss sheet after the keyboard

Tags: ios, swiftui

In SwiftUI, I open a `CommentsView` sheet like this:

```
@State private var selectedCategory: Category?

Button(category.name) {
    selectedCategory = category
}
.sheet(item: $selectedCategory) { category in
    CommentsView(category: category)
}
```

`CommentsView`:

```
struct CommentsView: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) private var presentationMode
    @State private var enteredComment: String = ""
    
    let category: Category
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("Add a comment", text: $enteredComment)
                .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())

            Button("Close") {
                presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is: I cannot dismiss the `CommentsView` after I focus on the text field and see the keyboard. Before focusing the "Close" button works as expected.

Comment: Works fine with Xcode 12.0 / iOS 14.

Comment: @Asperi You are right, it works in a sample project. I'm trying to understand what is different in my project.

Comment: @Asperi The reason was really strange. In absolutely another view (another sibling list item in a view where I open `CommentsView`) I used a "hand-made" grid as combination of V- and HStacks. Somehow, the part (only one 3rd of 4 row!) broke the behaviour of my `CommentsView` dismissing. Weird.

Answer (score 0):

Change the position of .sheet to be at the top VStack/HStack or ZStack, NOT at the Button View

```
.sheet(item: $selectedCategory) { category in
    CommentsView(category: category)
}
```